# vim line numbers - how to have them on by default?

Tags: vim, vi, editing, line-numbers

I can `:set number` from within a file I'm editing but how can I have them always be on by default?

Comment: Can you put the set command in your .vimrc?

Comment: where is that located ? Or do I just create one ?

Comment: You can make one.  It has to be in your home directory.  See my answer for details.

Comment: I created it, it worked.

Comment: It doesn't work when opening a directory using Vim, i have to use set nu again to turn numbering on, any workaround for that ?

Comment: I never understood why Vim and half the IDEs out there disable line numbers by default. Trying to save a few pixels?

Answer (score 556, accepted):

Add `set number` to your `.vimrc` file in your home directory.
If the `.vimrc` file is not in your home directory create one with
`vim .vimrc` and add the commands you want at open.

[Here's a site](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_vimrc_file) that explains the vimrc and how to use it.

Comment: Yeah.  Any time I want to set some defaults for a command line program I search their man page for `rc`.  It's a pretty common convention.

Comment: Create the file .vimrc if it does not exist in the home directory.

Comment: another great setting that's useful is `set relativenumber`

Comment: Simply run this command anywhere in your terminal: `echo "\nset nu" >> ~/.vimrc`. Now exit and reopen terminal session.

Comment: if you cant find .vimrc in your home directory, you can check it inside /etc/vim/vimrc

Comment: This works but maybe VIM's default profile no longer working. One example:  After creating .vimrc file java's default documentation comment's formatting not working correctly :(

Answer (score 99):

**To change the default setting to display line numbers in vi/vim:**

```
vi ~/.vimrc
```

then add the following line to the file:

```
set number
```

Either we can `source ~/.vimrc` or save and quit by `:wq`, now future vi/vim sessions will have numbering :)

Comment: by sudo it will also work if folder is restricted, which is often the case.

Comment: Yes, and you break access for the normal user which owns his home directory. This has been the cause of several bug reports and is just the wrong solution

Comment: also why use gedit? what if it's a server? or gedit is just not installed? make more sense to use vim :)

Answer (score 29):

```
set nu
set ai
set tabstop=4
set ls=2
set shiftwidth=4
```

Add the above code to your .vimrc file. if the .vimrc file is not present please create it in your home directory (/home/name of the user)

set nu -> Displays line numbers

set ai -> Enables auto-indentation

set ls=2 -> Shows a status line

set tabstop=4 -> Sets tab of length 4 spaces (it is 8 by default)

set shiftwidth=4 -> Number of spaces to use for each step of (auto)indent.  Used for `|'cindent'|`, `|>>|`, `|<<|`, etc. Please refer to Vim documentation [here](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Terminal > `su` > `password` > `vim /etc/vimrc`

Click here and edit as in line number (13):

```
set nu
```

[image: click here and Edit as "Line number (13)"]

Comment: Note that this would change default vim behavior for ALL users on a system, unless overridden by a users personal .vimrc in their home directory

Comment: I like the color scheme in this screenshot, which one are you using?

Comment: For ubuntu server the file location is `/etc/vim/vimrc`

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to add/edit .vimrc, you can start with

```
vi "+set number" /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 8):

I did not have a .vimrc file in my home directory. I created one, added this line:

```
set number
```

and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

in home directory you will find a file called ".vimrc" in that file add this code "**set nu**" and save and exit and open new vi file and you will find line numbers on that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Debian 7 64-bit.

I didn't have a .vimrc file in my home folder. I created one and was able to set user defaults for vim.

However, for Debian 7, another way is to edit /etc/vim/vimrc

Here is a comment block in that file:

```
" All system-wide defaults are set in $VIMRUNTIME/debian.vim (usually just
" /usr/share/vim/vimcurrent/debian.vim) and sourced by the call to :runtime
" you can find below.  If you wish to change any of those settings, you should
" do it in this file (/etc/vim/vimrc), since debian.vim will be overwritten
" everytime an upgrade of the vim packages is performed.  It is recommended to
" make changes after sourcing debian.vim since it alters the value of the
" 'compatible' option.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add any command you want to have by default to your `~/.vimrc` file (named `_vimrc` on Windows systems)