# How to enable line numbers for the Vim help permanently

Tags: vim, configuration-files, vim-plugin, line-numbers

I'd like to have line numbers permanently shown in vim, not only for regular text type files rather than for help files too.

Adding `set number` to the main configuration file of vim (`~/.vimrc`), as it is suggested in [vim line numbers - how to have them on by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274146/vim-line-numbers-how-to-have-them-on-by-default),  has no effect for the help file for me.

So where do I have to apply the appropriate configuration change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vim line numbers - how to have them on by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274146/vim-line-numbers-how-to-have-them-on-by-default)

Comment: As far I can see, it is not a duplicate, because it concerns to the help filetype and not to line numbering in general.

Answer (score 13):

my help shows line number by adding this line in my vimrc :

```
autocmd FileType help  setlocal number
```

It seems that you don't have to change vim's file, and don't need the root permission either.

Comment: I don't see "basic" and "advanced".  I have many plugins installed, it worked for me. If some plugins leads to the line above not working, you should report bug to the plugin owner.

Comment: I have to say that I was wrong. Your solution works. I didn't remark the 'autocmd FileType' directive and confused it with the 'set number' command. So I think, we can delete these comments, as your answer is correct.

Comment: @AndiHafner if you accepted this answer, other readers know this is the solution to your problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your working solution and for not to bother me, even if I was wrong with my poor "solution", which required admin rights, giving me the necessary time to review the issue among ones other daily obliges...

By the way: Could you explain to me why the '@User' directive doesn't work for me? I intended to address you like this, but by clicking the 'Save Edits' button, the stackoverflow webinterface deletes this entry...