# vim line numbers - how to have them on by default

Tags: vim

This question might seem identical to [This One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274146/vim-line-numbers-how-to-have-them-on-by-default#) but its not. 
I can :set number from within a file I'm editing but how can I have them always be on by default? 
Now as per that answer its recommended to add `set number` to **~/.vimrc file**. But you see there's no such file in my home file. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921441/where-is-my-vimrc-file) I tried to create that **.vimrc file**. It works and line number is shown. But problem is then all code highlighting is gone. How to resolve this? How to show line number with keeping code highlighting?

Comment: Add `syntax on` to your `.vimrc` file.

Comment: I did and its working perfectly. Thanks a lot. @Meninx-メネンックス

Comment: which version? e.g. `8.0.386` works just fine.

Comment: version 8.0.329 @Gang

Comment: @Leon, mine in fedora 25 build have syntax on by default

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vim line numbers - how to have them on by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274146/vim-line-numbers-how-to-have-them-on-by-default)

Comment: its not duplicate. i mentioned about those questions in my question. @HerbWolfe

Comment: The focus of your question, based on the title is getting line numbers to always be on. That is an exact duplicate of the questions you referenced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `set nu` and `syntax on` to your `.vimrc`

```
echo 'set nu' >> ~/.vimrc    
echo 'syntax on' >> ~/.vimrc
```

Answer (score 0):

added `syntax on` along with `set number` in **~/.vimrc file**. It works perfectly.